# Odoo 10 - Qweb report, multiply two fields

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

How can I multiply two fields in Odoo Qweb report?
I have seen that there is an option to sum several fields/items:

```
<t t-set="subtotal" t-value="sum(line.price_subtotal for line in layout_category['lines'])"/>
```

Can I multiply two fields/values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stay in your example:

```xml
<t t-set="subtotal"
    t-value="sum([line.field1 * line.field2 for line in layout_category['lines']])"/>
```